# Is this just encapsulation?

Tags: php, oop

I've this class. A plain old php object like this:

```
class Foo
{
    private $value;

    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

This `Foo::getValue()` is used to check if `Foo::$value` is 'foo' or 'bar'. Instead of use these, ...

```
if ($foo->getValue() == 'foo') {

}

if ($foo->getValue() == 'bar') {

}
```

**I want to expose these method.**

```
if ($foo->isValueFoo()) {

}

if ($foo->isValueBar()) {

}
```

How this refactoring operation is called? I want to promote e verbose but speaking interface. I don want to expose 'foo' or 'bar' scalars. Is a good or best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say if you have `100`'s of such string values for which you want to check, for that you have to exhibit such `100`'s function for getting this done. You can try something like `__call` magic function.

Here we are using [`__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) magic method to achieve this. This is just a sample code, you can do the required changes.

With this class object you can call any method with name `prefix:` `isValue` and `postfix:` `placeholderValueString`.

for getting postfix string value you can use either this `substr_replace($functionName, "", 0,strlen("isValue"))` or `substr($functionName, strlen("isValue"))`

or 
[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/855256)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class Foo
{
    private $value="foo";

    public function __call($functionName, $arguments=array())
    {
        if(strpos($functionName, "isValue")===0){
            $value= strtolower(substr_replace($functionName, "", 0,strlen("isValue")));
            if($this->value==$value){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
$object= new Foo();
echo $object->isValueFoo();
echo $object->isValueBar();
```

Comment: `substr($functionName, strlen("isValue"))`

Comment: @zerkms I think `strpos` can also be fine here.

Comment: I mean to replace this `substr_replace($functionName, "", 0,strlen("isValue"))`

Comment: I think the question was more directed towards best practices and theory than "how-to"

Comment: @ishegg the reason i suggested this. Just because let think if the OP has to check has to `20-30` values then for that moment OP has to define such `20-30` methods.

Comment: @SahilGulati yes. Absolutely.

Comment: @sensorario glad to help you friend... :)